# AJAX code isn't working within Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

All,
I have the following jQuery code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/oml/save_song.php",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "song_id=" + song_id + "&love_like_hate=love",
        async: false,
        success:function(response){
        alert(response.responseText1);
})
```

Then I have on the save_song.php file this code:

```
$song_id = $_POST['song_id'];
$love_like_hate = $_POST['love_like_hate'];

echo json_encode(array('responseText1' => 'It is: '.$love_like_hate));
```

For some reason if I run this code outside of wordpress it works perfectly fine, however when I'm executing this code from within wordpress it only posts the song_id and not the love_like_hate.

**EDIT:** When I mean within Wordpress I mean that I installed the Exec-PHP plugin and am writing the PHP and jQuery directly in one of my pages that I created. If I just run it on a normal php file without being a wordpress page it works fine.

Comment: Is the ajax function even firing?

Comment: @DavidNguyen Yes it is, I do get a response, my variables just aren't posting correctly.

Comment: If the PHP file is placed inside the webroot, wordpress won't come into action at all. So if it's the file in question, it looks more like that something with your javascript is broken.

Comment: @DavidNguyen I was testing other things before and it works. If I just change the $love_like_hate to $song_id it does display that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why but Wordpress didn't like the AJAX call so I made it in a POST. Here is the code that works:

```
jQuery.post("http://localhost/oml/save_song.php", { song_id: song_id, love_like_hate: "love" },
       function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }, "json");
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say "within", where do you mean exactly?

When clean-urls are turned on, Wordpress has control over the setting of its args because of mod_rewrite and its architecture. Which means that when you call a file, you're possibly not getting those args properly and its possibly not executing the file like you think it is.

More info please

Comment: Please see my Edit to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a while ago, and that you already accepted your own answer but since the fix was working around the problem using JSON, I figure I can help others with the original context.

The reason is that you need to hook wp_head in order to expose admin-ajax.php. WP needs this to execute ajax within it's php files. Here is a quick way to solve this. Put it in your functions.php file.

```
    /**
     * Echo ajaxurl
     */
    function head_script(){?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' );?>";
        </script>

    <?php }
add_action( 'wp_head', 'head_script' );
```